# ERROR Error: NbFormFieldComponent must contain [nbInput]

Tags: angular, nebular, form-fields

I'm facing an issue with Nebular and Angular 12, i'm trying to add an icon inside of an input, for that i'm using the  tag like the documentation told me to do.

But it return me this error  :

> **ERROR Error: NbFormFieldComponent must contain [nbInput]**

As anyone facing a similar issue ? here's the part of the code where i'm trying to use the nb-form-field:

```
<nb-form-field class="range-picker-container">
    <nb-icon nbPrefix icon="at-outline" pack="eva"></nb-icon>
    <input nbInput placeholder="{{ range.start | date }} - {{ range.end | date }}" [nbDatepicker]="rangePicker">
    <nb-rangepicker [range]="range" #rangePicker></nb-rangepicker>
</nb-form-field>
```

Of course i'm importing **NbFormFieldModule** in my Page.module.ts

Have a nice day !

Comment: You have wrapped date picker inside <nb-form-field> which is expecting nbInput element inside it and showing you an error. Remove that will fix your issue.

Comment: I get the same error if i remove <nb-rangepicker> from <nb-form-field>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for those who are facing the same issue here's the solution:

i've forgot to import

> NbInputModule,

with

> NbFormFieldModule,

in my Page.module.ts